# Waves and Sound

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics

An organ pipe of length 1.5 m is open at one end. What are the lowest two harmonic frequencies?

As it is open,

$V = 2lf$

$V = 343m/s$

Therefore: $343 = 2 \cdot 1.5 \cdot f$

$f = 114.33Hz$

But the answer is 57.16Hz and 171.5Hz.
Why?

Comment: http://www.studyphysics.ca/newnotes/20/unit03_mechanicalwaves/chp141516_waves/lesson51.htm

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the results, the pipe is clearly open at one end but closed on the other. Therefore $\lambda_n = \frac{(2n+1)L}{4}$

Your formalism is a bit unusual. If I can advise you, try to use something like this for harmonics:

$$f_n=\frac{c}{\lambda_n} = and \ so \ on$$

*Show explicitly the dependency on $n$.*